Presentism in Light of Relativity — It's About Time I Asked This Here
I've got a follow up question to Esmond's Does time exist if everything is in the present? and it goes like this:
According to presentism, only the present moment exists. But, according to Einstein's relativity, we can only speak of "Now-somewhere-else" in terms of convention, which basically means that we cannot speak of "Now-somewhere-else" existentially. So, the "Now" is inseparably tied to "Here"—or, as a mystic would put it, "Here and Now."
If we cannot existentially speak of "Now" somewhere else, then how can we say that something exists "somewhere else" or "over there"? While it is quite intuitive to say that the only thing that exists is the present moment, it would seem to be absurd to say that the only thing that exists is here and Now.

Potential Solution
A possible solution occurred to me:
The only entities that can truly be said to existentially exist are "I am" and the universe itself—these are the sources of our intuition of existence. "I think, therefore I am."
An object does not exist in this existential sense; it is merely an evolving configuration of the universe.
The question then becomes about the existence of someone else, now, somewhere else.
The key is to understand that "I am" is not personal but universal—it is of the universe itself.
I am not referring to a psychological "I am" or self, but rather to the mystical one—the Advaita Atman or Self with a capital S, said to be one with Brahman, the essential nature of the universe.
This "I am" exists always and everywhere, not just "here and now," thus resolving the question.
As for mere configurations of the universe into objects and psychological brains, these can align with the relativity of simultaneity, as they do not involve the presentism intuition originating from the "I am."
Does any a philosopher propose this solution to presentism in the context of relativity?

I think what you're saying is that presentism doesn't make sense in light of special relativity, where the slice of spacetime that is "now" depends on your velocity and position. Indeed, presentism does not make sense. Past and future exist and are as real as the present.

Now we are getting information from then over there.

I took the liberty of changing your title to something that indicated what the question was about.

See SEP, Presentism:"Perhaps the most serious objection to presentism comes from physics. In particular, the special theory of relativity (“STR”) has been presented as in direct tension with presentism." One of their responses is to adopt an alternative interpretation of relativity with something like Lorentz's aether and absolute nows. It makes predictions identical to Einstein's relativity, but most physicists reject such absolutely unobservable aether and simultaneity.

A demonstration that there is not just here & now and that the universal present is possible is given by Nasa's plan to create Coordinated Lunar Time.

@causative, the whole point of the question is that while relativity informed presentism does not make sense, believing that the past and future exist and are as real as the present make is way way more absurd.

There is a view that absolute present and revisionary interpretations of relativity are a dead end for presentism. They are not even supported by the core intuition, what does direct experience of here-now have to do with claiming copresent there-now on Alpha Centauri? Presentists resort to it because of fears of solipsism, but a better fit would be an event ontology with multiple here-nows and intersubjective reality coordinated not unlike Einstein's global reference frames, none privileged. Balaguer suggests moving presentism in this direction.

@Conifold can u turn this into an answer ?

@causative: Note that this is a three-tense vs. four-tense claim! We can make the indicated slice with three tenses, but the past will include the "elsewhere" or "elsewhen", the inaccessible regions neither in past nor future.

Does Presentism imply or require a universal 'now' as assumed by Newton?  That's what special relativity says doesn't exist.  If we interpret the mystical 'here and now' to be a frame of reference, we can still say your present and my present are still unique and real, we just might not agree on what has occurred. That feels like a solipsistic argument, but the fact is that our personal experience and every action we take is always in the present (meaning our respective individual presents.)

Multiple "nows", inter-connected causally  and relativistically (similarly to multiple "heres"), instead of a "global now" is a view that has been proposed by some authors.

@NikosM. Multiple interconnected nows do not solve the problem.

@nir the point is the rejection of a "global now" as problematic (eg relativistically). Then multiple"nows" (similarly to multiple "heres") naturally follows. The exact interconnection of these "nows" can vary or be defined in various ways.

@NikosM. No. The point is accommodating the intuition that drives presntism with relativity of simultaneity. Multiple nows fail to do that.

@nir imo your potential solution is an option to reconcile presentism with relativity. Your "now/present" is purely metaphysical though and that leaves the status of physical "nows" and their relation to the "absolute present" somewhat undetermined.

@NikosM. the presentist Now I'm interested in is not the now of the equations of a theory of physics - but the mysterious intuitive Now, described by Feynman as "What we mean by 'right now' is a mysterious thing which we cannot define" and by Einstein as reported by Carnap as "the experience of the Now means something special for man, something essentially different from the past and the future, but that this important difference does not and cannot occur within physics. That this experience cannot be grasped by science seemed to [Einstein] a matter of painful but inevitable resignation"

@nir you might be interested in Eternalism and Perspectival Realism About the ‘Now’

@nir you might also be interested in Relativity, the Open Future, and the Passage of Time

@nir see Relativity and the A-theory as well

Resource recommendation: physicist Lee Smolin defends something like presentism from the perspective of modern physics in Time Reborn (2013).
The supporting arguments are where most of the value of the book resides. Smolin can only make hesitant and hedged conclusions. We currently have no working theory of cosmological time to philosophically interpret - just general relativity cobbled together with extensions of quantum mechanics, statistical mechanics, and some mathematical guesswork. It's hard to hard to attach much physical meaning to any parts of such models except for the concrete predictions that they make, let alone philosophical import.
That being said... nobody should be making anything but hesitant and hedged conclusions in favor of eternalism, either, for the same reason.
Also, the epilogue feels like it was patched on after the editor insisted Smolin make the book "relevant". It can be skipped.
Of particular relevance to this question: doing relativity with an observer-dependent and convention-dictated "now somewhere else" is mathematically convenient, not mathematically, philosophically, or physically necessary. You can do relativity with a universal present. Instead of making the shape of the extended present observer-dependent and convention-dictated, you can make the shape of everything else observer-dependent and subject to arbitrary convention instead. If we give relativity the last word, we can't mean anything by "box bigger than me somewhere else now" except by arbitrary convention. But it's up to us whether we prefer to structure our mathematical model such that "somewhere else now" or "box bigger than me somewhere else" is the meaningless part.

You are confusing the question of whether something exists with the question of when it exists. What relativity shows is that 'now' only makes sense locally. For me, now is around 7am on 3rd June. Suppose there are three observers on some very distant galaxy, one stationary with respect to Earth, one walking towards Earth and one walking away. For the distant observer stationary relative to me, now on Earth is the same as it is for me, but for the other two, now on earth might be last Monday and next Monday. That arises from conventions used to synchronise clocks at a distance- it doesn't make any difference to my experience of now.

It seems you misunderstood my question. I am well aware of relativity of simultaneity - including the andromeda paradox - hence the question. I explicitly wrote that post-relativity simultaneity is merely conventional. For me it is totally absurd to think that a thing can exist anywhen else than Now. existence is irrevocably tied to Now by its nature.

I'm sorry if I misinterpreted your question. I agree completely that existence is tied to now. I don't see a problem with presentism provided it is interpreted sensibly. The foolish interpretation is to assume that 'the present' means a slice through all of spacetime orthogonal to one's time axis.

Don't you see the collision between presentism and special relativity ? What is happening right now on Mars? Is the famous astronaut Mark Watney dead or alive? Does he exist or not? There must be a fact of the matter about this, isn't there? Take a look at the SEP quote in conifolds anwser if you don't see the problem.

Incompatibility of (traditional) presentism with the standard interpretation of relativity is a well-known and self-acknowledged issue. SEP, Presentism discusses it at some length:

"Now, though there are many worries for presentism that come from metaphysics, perhaps the most serious objection to presentism comes from physics. In particular, the special theory of relativity (“STR”) has been presented as in direct tension with presentism. Simon Saunders (2002) gives us a clear picture of how things supposedly stand with respect to presentism and STR, as follows:"According to presentism, all that is physically real is the present — a system of physical events all of which are simultaneous with each other... But even if one knew all that there is to know, consistent with special relativity, one would not be able to say what this system of events might be. According to presentism, therefore, special relativity is radically deficient as a description of reality. It is blind to the sequencing of what is physically real.""

The most common response of traditional presentists is to adopt a neo-Lorentzian interpretation of relativity with something like Lorentz's aether and absolute nows, a privileged, metaphysically real frame of reference. It is developed, for example, by Craig in a number of books, see Balashov-Janssen critical review. It still makes predictions identical to Einstein's relativity, but most physicists reject such absolutely unobservable aether and simultaneity.
But there is also a view that absolute present and revisionary interpretations of relativity are a dead end for presentism. They are not even supported by the core intuition, what does direct experience of here-now have to do with claiming copresent there-now on Alpha Centauri? Presentists likely resort to them because of fears of solipsism. A better fit might be a perspectival event ontology with multiple here-nows and intersubjective reality coordinated not unlike Einstein's global reference frames, none privileged. Balaguer in How to Make Presentism Consistent with Special Relativity suggests moving presentism in this direction with his relativized presentism:

"We can get at this view of reality by seeing how it differs from a certain version of the moving spotlight theory... The idea is (roughly) as follows: if moving spotlight theorists can claim that there’s a relativistically kosher spotlight moving through the 4-dimensional block — and I think they can — then presentists can say that all that ever exists is what’s in that spotlight... Reality is not a 4-dimensional block; and there are no temporally extended 4-dimensional objects (or events)...


The important thing to notice about this view is that it entails the following surprising result. The relativity of existence: what exists is relative to a frame of reference... So the STR-presentist stance on existence is essentially equivalent to the standard stance on simultaneity... —i.e., there’s no frame-independent fact about whether E1 is “really” happening right now...  Note, however, that some things exist relative to all frames of reference, and so they exist objectively, absolutely, and frame-independently..."


I have read about 8 pages into Balaguer and if I understood correctly, and that is also reflected in your quote, then he simply elevates conventional simultaneity into metaphysically existential one - which seems as absurd as eternalism - or the other way around downgrades existence to mere convention which self defeats the idea.

Think about Mark Watney from the film 'The Martian' as he performs his final risky maneuver to board the rescue ship, while his NASA colleagues, 15 light minutes away on Earth, contemplate whether he is dead or alive. As they ponder his fate, their brains scream with the insistence that there must be a concrete fact of the matter about his existence at that very moment. He either exists or does not, independent of their knowledge. Not merely as a Balaguer convention.

@nir I think of it as only outlining formal contours of reconciling presentism with relativity and leaving metaphysics open-ended. It is like Tarski's T-schema, it is not meant to say what the truth is (although deflationists may reduce it to that), only gives a formal constraint on metaphysical theories of truth. So metaphysics of presentism with fundamental ontology of, say, here-now events, needs to present some aspects of intersubjective reality as perspectival (and some, that he mentions, as 'absolute'), which is not unusual for a subject-oriented position.

Can you try to explain this in layman terms ? wisdom cannot be loved if it cannot be understood to begin with. (this is what I loved about Dennett even if I rejected many of his ideas - he could always explain the most complex ideas in the simplest clearest terms)

The existential vividness of now that opposes eternalism with its completed 4D blocks is only intuited here. "The same now" at distant locations is only a projected abstraction, like those blocks, we have no intuitive reach out there. But that is all SR makes frame-dependent. When their brains scream, it is about a fact, but "at that very moment" is merely an analogical projection that adds vividness to empathy. The fact independent of their knowledge, the fact they care about in their transference, is not a time stamped fact. The time stamp on some 3D section is just abstracted perspective.

I don't understand what u r trying to say

The 'collision' between presentism and special relativity exists only if you assume that the present here is the same as the present there. The present is essentially local. You exist in a succession of local 'nows', and you can keep track of them by carrying a clock which records your proper time. I can do the same with a clock of my own. Where the confusion arises is if you project the time on your clock across a reference frame centred on you, and I do the same to create a reference frame centred on me. My 'now' in your frame need not be the same time as your now...

...if I am moving relative to you and I am some distance away, then you cannot know anything about my status 'now', since you have to wait for light from my now to reach you , which will not happen until some later time. My status is not the least uncertain to me, but it is completely uncertain to you. The uncertainties are distance-related, and vanish when two moving observers momentarily meet. Indeed, you can construct a thought experiment around this...

Imagine three pairs of girls and boys, each pair moving relative to the other pair, but the boy and girls within a given pair being stationary relative to each other and a great distance apart with synchronised watches. You can arrange the movements of the pairs so that all three girls pass each other at a point and all three boys pass each other at some other point a great distance away, and that the two meetings are simultaneous in the frame of one of the pairs. All three boys will agree that they met 'now' and all three girls will agree that they met 'now'...

...but their watches will tell them conflicting stories.

You question 'what is happening now on Mars?' is arbitrary, since it depends on what you take to be 'now' on Mars. A time-ordered series of events happens on Mars- which of them you equate with 'now' on the Earth is a matter of convention to do with the synchronisation of clocks. There is no uncertainty on Mars about the status of the events or the order in which they happen. If the astronaut dies at 12:06 Mars time then he dies at 12:06 Mars time.

OP: "While it is quite intuitive to say that the only thing that exists is the present moment, it would seem to be absurd to say that the only thing that exists is here and Now."
An individual observer "here" can say things (e.g. events) are happening/existing simultaneously elsewhere.  It's just that to another observer those same events are not simultaneous; the other observer has a different set of simultaneous events.
In other words, the present is personal.
By way of a simplified example, imagine an observer (Dasein A) and three astronauts in deep space moving in different frames: different directions and different velocities.  If all the frame details are known, calculations could be made accounting for time dilation etc. so that—with advanced planning—from the perspective of Dasein A everyone could snap their fingers in unison while saying Now!
From the perspective of any of the 3 astronauts the finger-snaps would certainly not be in unison, but from the perspective of Dasein A they would be.  Extending the plane of unison, Dasein A has their own objective present.  ('Objective' in the sense that it is the experience of the world that impinges on the subject, Dasein A.)

This answer uses a Kantian view of existence i.e. Critique of Pure Reason note 36 B287 :

"[existence] is the conjunction of the [notional] thing with perception."

although clearly only that which exists in the moment is specifically under consideration in this answer, e.g. finger-snaps.

no need to explain relativity of simultaneity again and again in the answers - it can be assumed as known by anyone engaging with this question anyway - but you are missing the point - like so many other people who read it - a conventional mathematical now is not the presentist Now discussed in this question - and renaming it a "personal now" does not change that fact. time to go back to the drawing board...

@nir Regarding mystical "I am", I would say this is 'Being': the non-reified side; the reified side being Dasein. For Heidegger Being is incomprehensible. Only the reified side Dasein has here & now. Put another way, Descartes cogito begins only with thought and time for thought, and this is the authentic time of Being (a priori). Objective time follows a posteriori, notwithstanding the realist objection that the cogito must be in the universe, but that's moot.  Interesting how Being is considered unapproachable. I think there is nothing left of presentism except the personal present now.

You might like this mind-blowing quote from Heidegger's Kantbuch, p. 197 "Time and the "I think" are no longer opposed to one another as unlike and incompatible; they are the same. Thanks to the radicalism with which, in the laying of the foundation of metaphysics, Kant for the first time subjected time and the "I think," each taken separately, to a transcendental interpretation, he succeeded in bringing them together in their primordial identity — without, to be sure, having seen this identity expressly as such."

Returning to your question though: "The only entities that can truly be said to existentially exist ..." Objectively, what exists is composed of understanding & perception, including de-aged versions of distant objects. (The veracity of objective existence is always questionable.) / "... are "I am" and the universe itself." 'Being' I mentioned earlier; the universe though — I know about cities, planets & stars but the universe as nature itself, that's pretty much as mysterious as Being. Perhaps they're in cahoots!

You ask about whether Mark Watney on Mars is alive "at that very moment". Unforunately that question is ill posed, because "at that very moment" is not well defined outside of "here". You can, of course, choose one of the infinitely many synchronization conventions in order to define what "at that very moment" means everywhere.
Many presentists adopt a Neo-Lorenzian view, that there is a special synchronization convention (a preferred frame of reference, if you will) that is not directly accessible to us but which nevertheless defines what "actually exists". In this view the statement "Mark Watney is alive on Mars now" is well defined but its truth is impossible to determine, even after the fact, because we cannot know how our "now" maps to the universal "now". Personally I dislike adding such unobservables to my world view, but to each their own.
What is universal and inarguable are the truth of propositions like "Mark Watney is still alive when his watch reads 12:15" in which things happen at the same time and place. If we adopt the usual Einstein synchronization convention in the frame at which we are at rest, and synchronize our watch with Mark's, then at 12:15 we will have to wait until signals from Mars reach us at 12:30 to know the truth of such a proposition. In that respect the proposition "Mark is alive now (at 12:15)" is very like the one "Bob on Earth will still be alive at 12:30". So in some respects the distant present is similar to the nearby future. One important difference is that we can directly affect the nearby future, while we cannot affect the distant present.

I don't understand this answer. It seems to me that you basically repeat or rephrase the question, while I'm interested in an answer. So no, I'm not at all interested in a conventional view, and I'm not really satisfied with an unobservable metaphysical plane of simultaneity—mainly because I don't like that solution. It's like insisting on sticking the "naive" Newtonian world-wide simultaneity back into the worldview of relativity. any comment on the solution I proposed ?

Re: your answer: appealing to something existing "always and everywhere" sounds like abandoning presentism, which explicitly rejects things existing at other times. Which I guess is one solution to the problems of presentism.

you misunderstood "existing always", I don't mean it in the eternalist block universe sense of the future and past existing (now), but rather more like in the presentist sense. put aside the relativity problem for a moment - with naive presentism the Now is the only thing that exists - it has always existed and always will exist - an ever changing now - while future and past are just human constructs.
